# Generate PDF from HTML using iText 7 in java data display in PDF vertically

Tags: java, html, angularjs, itext

```
File pdfDest = new File("/home/user/Desktop/demo.pdf");
        // pdfHTML specific code
       ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
       HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlFile, 
      new FileOutputStream(pdfDest), converterProperties);
```

Created pdf using HTML file using iText 7 in java. PDF is downloaded successfully but data in that PDF display in vertically CSS is not applied to PDF

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Using java I have created an HTML file and convert this HTML file into PDF using iText core 7. A PDF file is generated but all horizontal data displayed in a vertical column

Comment: I used Spire.PDF for Java for converting HTML strings to PDF and it can render CSS correctly. If you're also interested in this alternative solution, you could check [documentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.PDF-for-Java/Program-Guide/Conversion/Java-convert-HTML-to-PDF.html#B) for more details.